# ASP.NET Identity UserRole Table

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-identity

I am working on getting an ASP ListView control to populate Users based on the value from a DropDownList Control. On page load the list view will be populated with all users in the table. If I select a Role from the DropDownList I want it to display those users that belong to the selected role. I am using ASP Identity 2.0 and Role based authentication, with model binding. I need to create a join using LinQ that joins the User Table, The UserRole Table and the Role table, and I am kind of stuck. If I select a role nothing return back. The code is below.

This snippet binds the Roles to the DropDownList

```
    public IQueryable<IdentityRole> BindRoles()
    {
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(_db));
        var roles = from role in roleManager.Roles
                    orderby role.Name
                    select role;
        return roles;
    }
```

And this is the GetData Method for updating the ListView control based on the selection from the DropDownList

```
    public IQueryable<User> GetData([Control("RolesDropDown")] string Id)
    {

        if (Id != null)
        {
            var users = from u in _db.Users
                        where u.Id == Id
                        select u;
            return users;
        }
        else
        return _db.Users;
    }
```

Take in to consideration that I am new to Linq and trying to get this to work.

Will.

Comment: this is not classic asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot seem to find the schema online to reference but there is more then likely a cross reference table that would display the users in there roles.

The syntax you are using as your parameter for `GetData([Control("RolesDropDown")] string Id)` is new to me. I have never seen that. But if that was the ID of the ROLE you are looking to filter by then you would use that in your query below.

I would get the value from the drop down using `RolesDropDown.SelectedValue`

```
 public IQueryable<User> GetData([Control("RolesDropDown")] string Id)
    {

        if (Id != null)
        {
            var users = from u in _db.Users
                        join r in _db.UsersInRoles on u.UserID equals r.UserID
                        where r.RoleID == Id
                        select u;
            return users;
        }
        else
        return _db.Users;
    }
```

So look for your cross reference table of Roles and Users.

Comment: yeah the cross reference table is called AspUserRole, I think that is my problem, trying to get a reference to that table, I am trying to figure out to really use the ASP Identity 2.0 model but fail with everything I try to do. I think I am going to rewrite this using ADO.Net Sql and StoredProcedures and create my own tables as I will have full access to what I really want going on, but thanks for your response.